# Read certificates from PKI smart card with C#

Tags: authentication, smartcard, pki

I try to read the certificates from my PKI smart card with C#.
I read that the certificates are copied from the smart card into the certificate store on my computer when I insert my smart card into the card reader.

But when I check the number of the certificates in the different areas (My, AuthRoot, Root, ...) of my certificate store I get the same number, it does 
not matter if the smart card is inserted or not.

Here is how I check the number of certificates on my store:

```
var myStore = new X509Store(StoreName.AuthRoot, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
myStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
var count = myStore.Certificates.Count;
```

So how can I access the cerfificate on my smart card to verify the private key?

Thanks and kind regards
Friedhelm Drecktrah

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the card type. On a native card (one having a file system), each certificate is simply stored in a file and can be read using standard commands, most likely *READ BINARY*. To find out the file ID(s) you typically have to look into support information, like PKCS-11 or PKCS-15/ISO 7816-15 directory files your card provides. In case of several certificates you have to resolve for the purpose (typically also in the file).